# Mapping entities to DTOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF Entity that i want to map its attributes to a DTO with a function while using the fluent syntax.

Take the User for example I was able to make it work mapping it this way:

```
    public Task<List<JournalTransactionModel>> GetAllJournalRecords()
    {
        var journalRecords = db.JournalTransactions
            .Include(_ => _.JournalTransactionsAccounts)
            .Include(_ => _.User)
            .Select(_ => new JournalTransactionModel
            {
                JournalTransactionId = _.JournalTransactionId,
                Date = _.Date,
                Description = _.Description,
                User = new UserModel
                {
                    UserId = _.UserId,
                    FirstName = _.User.FirstName,
                    LastName = _.User.LastName,
                    FullName = _.User.FirstName + " " + _.User.LastName,
                    Email = _.User.Email,
                    UserName = _.User.UserName,
                    Password = _.User.Password,
                    UserRoleAndPermissions = new UserRoleModel
                    {
                        UserRoleId = _.User.UserRole.UserRoleId,
                        UserRoleName = _.User.UserRole.UserRoleName,
                        CanRead = _.User.UserRole.CanRead,
                        CanWrite = _.User.UserRole.CanWrite
                    }
                },
                TransactionAccounts = _.JournalTransactionsAccounts.Select(j => new JournalTransactionAccountModel
                {
                    JournalTransactionAccountId = j.Id,
                    JournalTransactionId = j.JournalTransactionId,
                    DebitAccount = j.DebitAccount != null ? new AccountModel
                    {
                        AccountId = j.DebitAccount.AccountId,
                        AccountCategoryName = j.DebitAccount.AccountCategory.AccountCategoryName,
                        AccountCategoryId = j.DebitAccount.AccountCategoryId,
                        AccountName = j.DebitAccount.AccountName,
                        IncreasesWhenDebited = j.DebitAccount.IncreasesWhenDebited
                    } : null,
                    CreditAccount = j.CreditAccount != null ? new AccountModel
                    {
                        AccountId = j.CreditAccount.AccountId,
                        AccountCategoryName = j.CreditAccount.AccountCategory.AccountCategoryName,
                        AccountCategoryId = j.CreditAccount.AccountCategoryId,
                        AccountName = j.CreditAccount.AccountName,
                        IncreasesWhenDebited = j.CreditAccount.IncreasesWhenDebited
                    } : null,
                    Amount = j.Amount,
                    Person = j.Person != null ? new PersonModel
                    {
                        PersonId = j.PersonId,
                        FirstName = j.Person.FirstName,
                        LastName = j.Person.LastName,
                        FullName = j.Person.FirstName + " " + j.Person.LastName,
                        Email = j.Person.Email,
                        SocialSecurityNumber = j.Person.SocialSecurityNumber,
                        PersonType = new PersonTypeModel
                        {
                            Id = j.Person.PeopleType.PeopleTypeId,
                            Name = j.Person.PeopleType.Name
                        }
                    } : null
                }).ToList()
            }).ToListAsync();
        return journalRecords;
    }
```

But when i tried to Create a function that returns UserModel I kept getting exceptions

```
    public Task<List<JournalTransactionModel>> GetAllJournalRecords()
    {
        var journalRecords = db.JournalTransactions
            .Include(_ => _.JournalTransactionsAccounts)
            .Include(_ => _.User)
            .Select(_ => new JournalTransactionModel
            {
                JournalTransactionId = _.JournalTransactionId,
                Date = _.Date,
                Description = _.Description,
                User = MapUserToModel(_.User),
                TransactionAccounts = _.JournalTransactionsAccounts.Select(j => new JournalTransactionAccountModel
                {
                    JournalTransactionAccountId = j.Id,
                    JournalTransactionId = j.JournalTransactionId,
                    DebitAccount = j.DebitAccount != null ? new AccountModel
                    {
                        AccountId = j.DebitAccount.AccountId,
                        AccountCategoryName = j.DebitAccount.AccountCategory.AccountCategoryName,
                        AccountCategoryId = j.DebitAccount.AccountCategoryId,
                        AccountName = j.DebitAccount.AccountName,
                        IncreasesWhenDebited = j.DebitAccount.IncreasesWhenDebited
                    } : null,
                    CreditAccount = j.CreditAccount != null ? new AccountModel
                    {
                        AccountId = j.CreditAccount.AccountId,
                        AccountCategoryName = j.CreditAccount.AccountCategory.AccountCategoryName,
                        AccountCategoryId = j.CreditAccount.AccountCategoryId,
                        AccountName = j.CreditAccount.AccountName,
                        IncreasesWhenDebited = j.CreditAccount.IncreasesWhenDebited
                    } : null,
                    Amount = j.Amount,
                    Person = j.Person != null ? new PersonModel
                    {
                        PersonId = j.PersonId,
                        FirstName = j.Person.FirstName,
                        LastName = j.Person.LastName,
                        FullName = j.Person.FirstName + " " + j.Person.LastName,
                        Email = j.Person.Email,
                        SocialSecurityNumber = j.Person.SocialSecurityNumber,
                        PersonType = new PersonTypeModel
                        {
                            Id = j.Person.PeopleType.PeopleTypeId,
                            Name = j.Person.PeopleType.Name
                        }
                    } : null
                }).ToList()
            }).ToListAsync();
        return journalRecords;
```

What is wrong up there?

This is the message I get:

> "ExceptionMessage": "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ACS.Hub.BusinessLogic.Models.UserModel MapUserToModel(ACS.Hub.Repository.User)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: EF query provider does not support custom methods inside the query expression tree. If you want to easily define and reuse mappings, [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) package (especially with `QueryableExtensions` `ProjectTo`) is just for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LINQ` query expression translated on server `IQueryable` query. In your case are not supported because your subQuery must be calculate on memory. `MapUserToModel` method want to use calculated data. If you want to fill user propery by `MapUserToModel` method  you can get data on memory using by `ToList()` before `Select` data.

```
var journalRecords = db.JournalTransactions
            .Include(_ => _.JournalTransactionsAccounts)
            .Include(_ => _.User)
            .ToList()
            .Select(_ => new JournalTransactionModel
            {
              ....
            }
```

Comment: Oh i understand now, but this is a bad practice don't you think ? if i just asked LINQ to bring me everything in all tables then map them to my user models this would affect performance big time.

And also on the other side if i just map everything like that everytime, for example i almost use this User in every query i make. this would result in so much redundant code.

Comment: @Willy Correct. And not only LINQ will create a query that loads all the data from the tables but you will also do the mapping In Memory which means you are wasting RAM memory and also processing time for doing the calculations in memory. Although the additional utilization of the processor is very small, depending on the user load that your web app will have it can easily become a burden in terms of how many parallel users can your app serve with a single server. So keep that in mind.

Comment: @Willy Check out my edited answer for a solution of the redundant code problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call your custom defined methods inside a linq query. The reason for that is that behind the scenes LINQ converts all your LINQ statements into a valid SQL statement. And the SQL language certainly does not have a definition for a function called MapUserToModel. One solution is to take the code out of your `MapUserToModel` method and place it directly inside the LINQ query.

---

***EDIT:***
We have discussed why you can't use a custom method inside the query that we want to execute on the SQL server and we have also discussed that it is not a good thing to use ToList() and do the mapping in memory. However you are still facing the issue with writing redundant code whenever you want to map the User. Since I am very annoyed of having/seeing redundant code I took some time to play with this kind of challenge and came to a solution which will allow you to write the mapping code only in one place and use it anywhere you need it. So, let's say that our original user entity which we keep in the database is called `User` and our DTO class is called `UserModel`. Here is the code:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public DbUser DbUser
    {
        set
        {
            Username = value.UserName;
            Email = value.Email;
            Birthday = value.Birthday;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how we would use this:

```
var journalRecords = db.JournalTransactions
.Include(_ => _.JournalTransactionsAccounts)
.Include(_ => _.User)
.Select(_ => new JournalTransactionModel
{
    JournalTransactionId = _.JournalTransactionId,
    Date = _.Date,
    Description = _.Description,
    User = new UserModel
    {
        DbUser = _
    }
    ...
});
```

I think the code is self explanatory but in short, the trick here is that on our DTO UserModel class we add a property for the original DbUser entity and we only create a setter method which accesses each property from the DbUser and assigns it to each corresponding property of itself. So if you need to add or remove some properties for the mapping in the future, you just go to this one setter method and implement the changes here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `toList()` before calling the `Select()`, but this can be seriously degrade the performance of the query. That's why you get an error because Linq does not know how to translate your custom methods into SQL as Dejanin says. But when you call the `toList()` method, the previous query is executed and the operations are not done with SQL anymore.